# number_with_precision formatting number with hyphens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting

`number_with_precision` (a helper method included in ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper) is hyphenating the output number. This started happening in our staging and production environments after we upgraded Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.10. We are still running Rails 3.2.15.

Example:

```
>> include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
>> number_with_precision(10000)
=> "10-000,000"
```

In my development machine it returns `"10000,000"`, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@apneadiving pointed it was a locale problem, and it certainly was.
In my locale files I had:

```
es:
 number:
   precision:
     format:
       delimiter: "-"
```

Precision property is used used in number_with_precision as pointed in http://ruby-i18n.org/wiki/translations-available-in-ruby-on-rails.

Deleting that configuration fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's due to a locale somehow.

To be sure, provide the (non) delimiter explicitly:

```
number_with_precision(10000, delimiter: '')
```

to avoid the hassle of repeating the option create your own helper or in application_helper:

```
def number_with_precision(number, options = {})
  options[:delimiter] ||= ''
  super(number, options)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Passing the delimiter: '' parameter fixes the issue but I want to get it working by default as before. Setting locale: :en fixes the issue as well, but my default_locale is :es. Should I install the es locale in the server? $> locale -a shows it is not installed.